# CentOS remote syslog message stores in two files

Tags: linux, centos, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I am using rsyslog server in CentOS steam. want to log each remote server log message in `/data/log/<hostname>.log` and local server message in `/var/log/message` file.

using below configuration, both remote log server log and local server log message store in `/var/log/message` and `/data/log/<hostname>.log` files.

How can I log remote server log message only in `/data/log/<hostname>.log` file?

`/etc/rsyslog.conf` file

```
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")
$FileCreateMode 0640
module(load="builtin:omfile" Template="RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat")
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon

$InputTCPServerRun 6514
$MaxOpenFiles 100000
module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.Use="off")
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state")
$template FILENAME,"/data/logs/%HOSTNAME%.log"
*.* ?FILENAME
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

Comment: You need to use a ruleset, see [for example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631669/119298).

Comment: @meuh Thanks this helped

Comment: as @meuh posted, this post has the correct answer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631660/rsyslog-prevent-local-host-logging-twice/631669#631669

Comment: yes, it helped me. its working